# How to check a log of which tasks have been opened on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager, macos

I'm running macOS 10.15.6 (19G2021) on a Late 2018 Mac mini. For the last few months, I have been observing a somewhat strange phenomenon: Every hour or so, usually when running the Chrome browser, a task opens for a split second and then closes again. The currently active window becomes inactive during this time, then enters the foreground again.

To figure out which task is causing this, I'd like to create/look at a log of all tasks that are opened and closed on my Mac. Then I could have a look right after it happened.

I couldn't find any log entries of opening/closing tasks in the "Console" app. Do you know a good way of checking a history of all opening/closing tasks? Possibly, this phenomenon could also be due to Chrome's graphics system refreshing somehow. Malwarebytes doesn't find any threats on my system. Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to have Xcode downloaded ? if so, use instruments.app  > activity monitor.

Comment: Oh of course. Thank you, I'll gladly read the docs!